# viewport meta tag-required be before any other styles either embed or linked?

Tags: viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

this required be before any other styles either embed or linked?

Answer (score 0):

NO,HTMLMetaTag is independent to CSS.

I think HTMLMetaTag will be executed before any styles, as CSSDeviceAdaptation is important than metatag when setting viewport.